# HTTP POST request from react client app to spring-boot server returns 400 error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, spring-boot

I have configured a POST request in my react app like this:

```
await fetch('http://localhost:8080/api/room', { credentials: 'include' }, {
  'method': 'POST',
  'headers': {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': true
  },
  'body': JSON.stringify(somedata),
})
.then(function (response) {
  console.log(response);
})
.catch(function (error) {
  console.log('Error', error);
});
```

In my spring-boot app I have a controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/room", produces = "application/json", method = {RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST})
public ResponseEntity<Room> createRoom(@Valid @RequestBody Room room) throws URISyntaxException {
    Room result = roomService.saveOrUpdate(room);
    return ResponseEntity.created(new URI("/api/room/" + result.getRoomClientId()))
            .body(result);
}
```

In my browser console I get this response:

```
Response {type: "cors", url: "http://localhost:8080/api/room", 
redirected: false, status: 400, ok: false, …}
```

In my spring-boot app console I get this error:

```
2019-04-08 16:31:42.742  WARN 86177 --- [io-8080-exec-10] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Required request body is missing: public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<com.sbpoc.app.db.entity.Room> com.sbpoc.app.db.controller.RoomController.createRoom(com.sbpoc.app.db.entity.Room) throws java.net.URISyntaxException]
```

Error says, request body is missing?

**Update**

```
import uniqid from 'uniqid';
const someData = {
  roomNumber: uniqid(),
}
```

Room Entity:

```
@Entity
public class Room implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 3433823138738252949L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

private String roomNumber;

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getRoomNumber() {
    return roomNumber;
}

public void setRoomNumber(String roomNumber) {
    this.roomNumber = roomNumber;
}
```

}

Comment: Could you add the output of `JSON.stringify(somedata)` and the contents of the `Room` class?

Comment: @Misantorp updated!

Comment: If the `body` is empty you'll need to show the output of `JSON.stringify(somedata)`, ie. by doing a `console.log(JSON.stringify(somedata))` if I am to try to help you out

Comment: @Misantorp I have managed to resolve the issue, the body definitely had data. The request ignored the second block of '{ method: ... }', so I merged the objects to one

Comment: Glad you figured it out :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to include the credentials option into one object as such:

```
fetch('http://localhost:8080/api/room', 
  {
    method: 'POST', 
    credentials: 'include',
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': true
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(data)
  }
)
.then(res => console.log(res));
```

I also made use of @PostMapping instead in the springboot app:

```
@PostMapping("/room")
public ResponseEntity<Room> createRoom(@Valid @RequestBody Room room) throws URISyntaxException {
    log.info("Request to create room: {}", room);
    Room result = roomService.saveOrUpdate(room);
    return ResponseEntity.created(new URI("/api/room/" + result. getRoomClientId()))
            .body(result);
}
```